# RESTful Services - GET and POST requests not working

Tags: java, json, eclipse, web-services, rest

I am using an example given in [RESTful Java client with Jersey client](http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-rs/restful-java-client-with-jersey-client/)
to practice GET and POST requests. I downloaded the code and tried running on Eclipse Neon. I used Tomcat v8.0. But it's not giving the intended output as explained in that demo. The 'GET' request is giving response in JSON format but there is no line as "Output from server...". Am I missing a point here? And when I try 'POST' request, its showing an error HTTP Status 405 - Method Not Allowed.
Screenshot is below.

[image]

Could anyone help me understand where I am going wrong in this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How can you get a screenshot showing a browser page by running a console application printing stuff on the standard output? What are you doing exactly?

Comment: I tried running the project by 'right click on project -> run as -> run on server'. But that gave me an error as 'Do you want to save this file (get.json)?'. That's why I used that URL in browser. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Of course: the post URL, as its name indicates, is supposed to be accessed using POST, not GET. The tutorial covers two things: a server part, running on a wab server, and offering services (one accissible with GET, one accessible with POST), and a client part, implemented as two simple executable classes, that each connect to the server to invoke the REST services (one for GET, one for POST). So you need to deploy the server part on the server, let it run, and then execute the two main classes (i.e. Run as -> application or something like that) to see the output in the console.

Answer (score 1):

It would appear that URL only supports GET.

Try:

```
curl -XPOST http://localhost:8080/RESTfulExample/rest/json/metallica/post
```

It would appear the GET version of that is (which you can user in your browser):

```
curl -XGET http://localhost:8080/RESTfulExample/rest/json/metallica/get
```

Answer (score 0):

1. With the HTTP GET request, you are getting what you want. The tutorial means that the line *after* "Output from Server .... " is what the server sends.
2. With the HTTP POST request, you should post something using an interface (e.g. Postman extension of Chrome browser, curl command line client etc.). Merely connecting to the POST URL in the browser is not going to actually post anything to the server. Please see Wikipedia on HTTP GET and HTTP POST request.

Comment: Thank you for guiding me here! I will read the Wikipedia and work on POST request. But could you please tell me why there is a line System.out.println("Output from Server .... \n"); in the tutorial code? Where do we get to see that output line?

Comment: Uh. Look for `System.out.println("Output from Server .... \n");` in the source code snippet.

Comment: @Sushma the JerseyClientPost class is a simple class with a main method. You execute it (from the IDE or the command line), and it prints to System.out. Just like you executed your very first HelloWorld class printing Hello World on the console.